# Bootstrap 5 card footer not staying at the end of the page

Tags: python-3.x, django, bootstrap-5

I am still new to creating websites with Bootstrap and have come across an issue with adding a footer to my base.html template in Django. What I want is that the footer stays at the end of page and shows when I scroll to the end of that page. Here is my base.html code:

```
   {% load static %}
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Vlereso Profesorin</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Google Font -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'vleresoprofesorin/css/master2.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/master.css' %}">
  </head>
  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light mynav">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav leftnav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">Kreu</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="navbar-brand dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Universitetet</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Universiteti i Tiranës</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Universiteti Politeknik i Tiranës</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Universiteti i Mjekësisë, Tiranë</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Universiteti i Sporteve të Tiranës</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Universiteti i Arteve Universitet</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Universiteti Bujqësor i Tiranës</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Universiteti "Aleksandër Moisiu", Durrës</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Universiteti "Aleksandër Xhuvani", Elbasan</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Universiteti "Luigj Gurakuqi", Shkodër</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Universiteti "Eqrem Çabej", Gjirokastër</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Universiteti "Fan S. Noli", Korçë</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Universiteti "Ismail Qemali", Vlorë</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <a class="navbar-brand" id="logo" href="{% url 'home' %}">
            <img src="{% static 'images/mainlogo.png' %}" alt="Missing image" width="260px" height="220px">
          </a>
          {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item userbuttons">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="{% url 'accounts:logout' %}">Logout</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          {% else %}
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="{% url 'accounts:login' %}" id="loginbtn">Login</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="{% url 'accounts:signup' %}" id="signupbtn">Rregjistrohu</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <style>@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Benne&display=swap');</style>



    <div class="container text-center mycontent">
      {% block content %}

      {% endblock %}
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="card text-center fixed-bottom">
          <div class="card-header" style="font-family: 'Benne', serif;">
            <q>Eksperiencat janë mësuesi më i mirë</q><br>
            <em><i>-Jordan B. Peterson</i></em>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Kontakto me Zhvilluesin</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Për çdo problem ose paqartësi me faqen mund të na kontaktoni duke perdorur butonin më poshtë:</p>
            <a href="mailto:infovleresoprofesorin@gmail.com" class="btn btn-primary">Kontakto</a>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer text-muted">
            Copyright © 2021
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="push"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer"></div>

    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

and here is my CSS file attached to the base.html template:

```
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(155, 207, 197, 0), rgba(155, 207, 197, 0.45));
 font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
 font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 900;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

p {
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.container-fluid {
 height: auto;
}

.leftnav {
 margin-left: auto;
}

#logo {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

#loginbtn {
 margin-right: auto;
}

#signupbtn {
 border: 2px solid rgba(155, 207, 197);
 border-radius: 8px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
}

.mb-3 {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 width: 500px;
}

.form-control {
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 width: 500px;
}

.btn-outline-primary {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
 }

#navbarDropdown {
 margin-bottom: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

.mycontent {
 overflow: auto;
}

.card-body {
 background-color: rgba(155, 207, 197, 0.3);
}

.wrapper {
 min-height: 100%;
 height: auto !important;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto -250px;
}

.footer, .push {
 height: 250px;
}
```

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated. Thank you

[Image without scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jN6A3.png)

[Image with scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGKY3.png)

Comment: Have you tried these? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: `position: sticky;`

Comment: I have already tried every possible CSS combination, however I tried with sticky again and same issue. I'm thinking it is the position of the footer in relevance to the 
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}

However, I have moved it in different parts of the HTML code and the issue remains.